# Solve the inequality $-1<(1/x^2)<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I realise it must be split into $-1<(1/x^2)$ and $(1/x^2)<1$
and solving both yields 'All $x$ except $x=0$' and '$x>-1, x<-1$'respectively. Why is it that I must find the intersection of these two solutions,  which is $x>-1, x<-1$?

Comment: because it is 'and', and both inequalities must be satisfied that will be only possible only if you intersect both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can replace your inequality by $$0\le \frac{1}{x^2}<1$$ for all real $x.$ Then it is enough to consider the inequality $$1<x^2$$ $$0<(x-1)(x+1).$$ This gives $x<-1$ **or** $x>1.$

Answer (score 1):

1) LHS is true $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
2) RHS: rewrite it as $\frac{1- x^2}{x^2}<0$. Clearly the denominator is always positive, so we need to find for what $x$ the numerator is negative. Just solve $(1+x)(1-x)<0$ to find $ x < -1 \cup x > 1$